# Provide validation for minimum number inserted in Yii2

Tags: php, validation, yii2

i am having trouble with this validation,

how can i validate minimum number to be inserted in

```
$form->field($modeldetails, "[{$i}]qty")->textInput()
```

based on sum of table quantity field with parameter to filter from `$form->field($model, 'tgl')` because i cannot simply add range validation in models rule.

I need a function to get paramater from two models `($model,$modeldetails)`, and process summary of quantity, if user inserted more than minimum sum then show an error in quantity field.

**View activeform field for header** ( using dynamic form )

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'dynamic-form')]); ?>


        <?= $form->field($model, 'tgl')->widget(DatePicker::classname(), [
                'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Enter Transaction Date ...'],
                'type' => DatePicker::TYPE_COMPONENT_APPEND,
                'pluginOptions' => [
                    'autoclose'=>true,
                    'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                    'todayHighlight' => true
                ],

            ]); ?>
```

**View activeform field for detail**

```
<?php DynamicFormWidget::begin([
            'widgetContainer' => 'dynamicform_wrapper', // required: only alphanumeric characters plus "_" [A-Za-z0-9_]
            'widgetBody' => '.container-items', // required: css class selector
            'widgetItem' => '.item', // required: css class
            'limit' => 15, // the maximum times, an element can be cloned (default 999)
            'min' => 1, // 0 or 1 (default 1)
            'insertButton' => '.add-item', // css class
            'deleteButton' => '.remove-item', // css class
            'model' => $modeldetail[0],
            'formId' => 'dynamic-form',
            'formFields' => [
                'id_brg',
                'qty',

            ],
        ]); ?>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4>
                Detail
                <button type="button" class="add-item btn btn-success btn-sm pull-right"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Add</button>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="container-items"><!-- widgetBody -->
            <?php foreach ($modeldetail as $i => $modeldetails): ?>
                <div class="item panel panel-default"><!-- widgetItem -->
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title pull-left"></h3>
                        <div class="pull-right">
                            <button type="button" class="remove-item btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <?php
                            // necessary for update action.
                            if (! $modeldetails->isNewRecord) {
                                echo Html::activeHiddenInput($modeldetails, "[{$i}]id");
                            }
                        ?>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <?= $form->field($modeldetails, "[{$i}]id_brg")->label('Nama')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
                                        'data' => $brg,
                                        'language' => 'en',
                                        'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select an item ...'],
                                        'pluginOptions' => [
                                            'allowClear' => true
                                        ],
                                    ]);?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <?= $form->field($modeldetails, "[{$i}]qty")->textInput() ?> 
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- .row -->

                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- .panel -->
<?php DynamicFormWidget::end(); ?>
```

**my models for details**

```
class Detail extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'detail';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['id_brg', 'qty'], 'required'],
            [['kode', 'id_brg', 'qty'], 'integer'],

        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'kode' => 'Kode',
            'id_brg' => 'ID Barang',
            'qty' => 'Qty',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getLinkheader()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Transaksi::className(), ['kode' => 'kode']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getItems()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Barang::className(), ['id' => 'id_brg']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Core Validators [integer](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-core-validators.html#integer)

```
[['qty'], 'integer', 'min' => 123],
```

Comment: Yup, but still need more step to get dynamic min value

Answer (score 1):

Use custom validator. Simple example is [inline validator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html):

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['id_brg', 'qty'], 'required'],
        [['kode', 'id_brg', 'qty'], 'integer'],
        ['qty', function ($attribute, $params) {
            /* calculate min value */
            $min = 123;
            if ($this->$attribute > $min) {
                $this->addError($attribute, "Qty must be less than {$min}.");
            }
        }],
    ];
}
```

Comment: I agree with you, but my problem is how to get the value of $form->field($model, 'tgl') from the view, so i can use to calculate with filtering that value and then the result i put in $min.

Comment: Make complex model contains both $model and $modeldetails. Use its for calc and validate qty from fgl.

Comment: Yes, but i don't know how to do